# Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe on CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud, unsubscribe

Recently I have been setting up to sync unsub data on CRM to MC.
I mentioned sync but what I want is this link(highlighted yellow) to work well.

[image]

However when I click the link, this error message comes up.

[image]

I managed to enable my user to use this functionality, but not for other users who has exact same roles on CRM and MC.

I also read this article : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000363401&type=1

Is there limit number of users that able to use this functionality or am I missing some process except ones in the article ?
Has anyone else encountered the same error before and have any ideas to fix it ?

If so please let me know, how you did to solve this.
Any tips would be great.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

That article is correct, you must have your CRM user integrated with your Marketing Cloud user to be able to use that Unsubscribe link, along with those other two links. The following doc will also walk you through integrating both of your users:

Connect your Marketing Cloud user with your Salesforce user
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000354555&type=1

There is not a limit on how many users you can integrate, but there has to be a 1-to-1 relationship, meaning one CRM user to one Marketing Cloud user.

Comment: Hi @lilDabz, thank you for your comment. What I was missing is to log in on both account as THE user on same browser. This article and you saved me. I really appreciate it ! Thank you again.